# Picture rotation angle issue in various android devices

Tags: android, orientation

I am working on small app where i am re sizing bitmap using  `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`. I am using code below to get the rotation angle of image clicked and based on the rotation angle i am rotating and re-sizing image to. This works very well without any issue in samsung galaxy s4(Android 4.3 Jellybean) but same code is not working in  Motorola Moto E(Android 4.4.4): it is **not returning angle** so i am not able to resize image properly.

Please guide me for this issue..How can i handle this on various devices.Thanks in advance

```
public int getCameraPhotoOrientation(){
    int rotate = 0;
    try {
       this.getContentResolver().notifyChange(Uri.fromFile(outputImage), null);
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(outputImage.getAbsolutePath());
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

    switch (orientation) {
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
        rotate = 270;
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
        rotate = 180;
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
        rotate = 90;
        break;
    }

   // Log.i("RotateImage", "Exif orientation: " + orientation);
   // Log.i("RotateImage", "Rotate value: " + rotate);
    utilitycls.showCustomToastMessage(this,""+orientation,0);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return rotate;}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested i have used ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL in switch.My motorola device returns -1 Oreintation .based on the orienation i am setting width and hieght.It is working for both S4 and motorola.But still i am clueless for other devices.

rotate= getCameraPhotoOrientation();  //getOrientation(this);//

```
        // utilitycls.showCustomToastMessage(this,"Rotation::"+rotate,1);


        if(rotate == 0 || rotate == 180)
        {
            finalW=480;
            finalH=270;
              //  resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,  480,270, false);
        }
        else if(rotate == 90 || rotate == 270)
        {
            bmp=RotateBitmap(bmp, rotate);

            finalW=270;
            finalH=480;

        }
        else 
        {
            if(bitmapW >= bitmapH)
            {
                finalW=480;
                finalH=270;
            }
            else
            {
                finalW=270;
                finalH=480;
            }



        }



        resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,  finalW,finalH, false);










public int getCameraPhotoOrientation(){
    int rotate = 0;
    try {
       this.getContentResolver().notifyChange(Uri.fromFile(outputImage), null);
      //  File imageFile = new File(imagePath);

    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(outputImage.getAbsolutePath());
    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

    switch (orientation) {
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
        rotate = 270;
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
        rotate = 180;
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
        rotate = 90;
        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
        rotate = 0;
        break;
    case 0:
        rotate = -1;
        break;
    }

   // Log.i("RotateImage", "Exif orientation: " + orientation);
   // Log.i("RotateImage", "Rotate value: " + rotate);
    utilitycls.showCustomToastMessage(this,""+orientation,0);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return rotate;
```

}